# how to write a function to split out elements in the list to string in python

Tags: python, list, function

How to create a function that would split out the list into each variable

For Example : if each list has "n" elements

```
mylist = [var,var1,var2,var3]
anotherlist = [var,var1,var2,var4,var5]
```

--> result

create a function that would split out these variables list

```
split(mylist) --> 
x = var
x1 = var1
x2 = var2
: 
xn = varn
```

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to do? this doesnt make sense to me ...

Comment: This question is quite vague, please try to describe more clearly what you mean by "split out".

Comment: Do you actually want to copy each of your list values into separate variable?? If yes, then Why On Earth would you want to do that??  It doesn't make sense to me to write a function to split a LIST...

Comment: well, I got "mylist" from extracting xml package that stored in a database. Each record that I am extracting has "n" elements in its root().  So I need to put each elements within this root ( or record ) and stored to temp variables , say  x ( x , x1,x2 x3 .. and so on ) My final goal is store this x , x2, x3 , x4 , .. xn to another database using pyodbc to connect to another database

Comment: Oh.. x1 x2 x3 why ? , the answer is that I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: @JPC: Don't save them as temporary variables. Just keep them in a list like they already are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question, but do you mean something like that:

```
def print_var(variable_list):
    for i, element in enumerate(variable_list):
        print 'x' + str(i) + ' = ' + element

mylist = ['var','var1','var2','var3']
anotherlist = ['var','var1','var2','var4','var5']
print_var(mylist)
print_var(anotherlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, as in "feasible" - but it is unlikely it is useful for anything.  If the length of your list is unknown to start with, how good would you be with variables named "x" if you don't know the range of possible values for  in your code.

Python, as a language, is designed so that you have variables with known names -- any dynamic data you come across along should be kept in a dynamic data structure, like a dictionary, or, since in this case the only identifier you have are the indexes, the list itself.

In other words, you are better off with:

```
mylist = [var,var1,var2,var3]
mylist[0]
mylist[1]
...
```

Than with what you ask for - since you can check the lenght of mylist, or simply
loop over its elements with a for statement.

That said, it is important to remember Python does feature assignemtn unpacking, so if
your list have a known lenght, you can simply do:

```
mylist = [var1, var2, var3, var4]
x1, x2, x3, x4 = mylist
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is quite vague. I'm applying what I can understand from it that you want to assign the variables from anotherlist to the names in mylist. In that case you will want to use a dictionary like this.

```
mydict = {}
for i in xrange(len(mylist)):
    mydict[mylist[i]] = anotherlist[i]
```

Then you can freely use the `mydict` with the values from `mylist` as keys.

Comment: I don't think he wanted to use the `anotherlist` variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems to me that the question is about dynamically assigning variables. Second, it is a bad idea. You should use a dictionary instead. Still, here is an example what you should not do, but it seems to answer your question.

```
In [196]: def assign_variables(mylist):
     ...:     for idx,item in enumerate(mylist):
     ...:         var='x'+str(idx)
     ...:         globals()[var]=item
     ...:         

In [197]: mylist=['var','var1','var2','var3']

In [198]: assign_variables(mylist)

In [199]: x1
Out[199]: 'var1'

In [200]: x2
Out[200]: 'var2'
```

With a dict you could try smth like this:

```
>>> def var_dict(mylist):
...     d={}
...     for idx,item in enumerate(mylist):
...         var='x'+str(idx)
...         d[var]=item
...     return d
... 
>>> mylist=['var','var1','var2','var3']
>>> mydict=var_dict(mylist)
>>> mydict
{'x0': 'var', 'x1': 'var1', 'x2': 'var2', 'x3': 'var3'}
>>> mydict['x1']
'var1'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks root, can you please give me a recommendation of what should I do or sample program ? I just made this program up as it goes. Frankly, this is my first python program or a program ever. So any recommendation would be very helpful.